# Add objects in seeds for association has_and_belong_to_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following models

```
class Blind
  has_and_belongs_to_many :fabrics
end

class Shade
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shades
end

Join table :blindes_shades
```

For blindes `blind1`, `blind2` and `blind3` I want to create shades `[shade1, shade2...shade9]`. I want to add in seed file for creating objects defaults.

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create 9 Shades
2. Create 3 Blinds
3. Associate them

Follow this:

```
Shade.create({shade: attributes}, {shade: attributes})

Blind.create({blind: attributes}, {blind: attributes})

Blind.all.each do |blind|
  blind.shades = Shade.where(your condition) # Shade.all OR Shade.first(9)
end
```

Comment: for blind object now all fine, but if i select shade object, blin_id = nil

Comment: How come you have `blind_id` in shades if you are using `HABTM`?

Comment: The entry will go in join table and you can call `shade.blinds` or `blind.shades`

Comment: You only need `blind_id` in shades table if you have association `Blind has_many :shades` and `Shade belongs_to :blind`